# identity() / scope_identity() doesn't work in H2 when assigned

Tags: database, h2

Using H2 embedded Java dabatase, I have a problem with identity() and scope_identity(). These functions doesn't seem to work when assigned to variable:

Let's have simple table:

```
create table test3 (x int IDENTITY);
```

This works, as expected returning the last value inserted:

```
insert into test3 values (default);
select scope_identity()
```

The following construct should return the same but returns null

```
insert into test3 values (default);
set @a=scope_identity();
select @a;
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in H2?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `set` actually resets the scope identity (to null) because it is not a query. Only statements that returns a result, such as `select` and `call`, are queries. So what you can do is:

```
select @a := scope_identity();
```

This works. I agree it is unexpected that `set` doesn't work in this case, and I will check if it is possible to support it.

Comment: Thomas, is there a bug report (or mailing list thread) we can follow for progress on this issue? I'd also like to see it fixed. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/h2-database/0xJsP993RHY/RYXBoD3UiJ0J for a related discussion.